# Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime does not exist After Magento2 Migration

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

When Creating a Customer registration I am getting this error

> "We can't save the customer"

on front end. I have Migrated from Magento 1.9.1.1 to Magento 2.3.3.

This is error log:Exception message: `Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime` does not exist.

Comment: Replace `Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime` to `Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Date`. and check it.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check whether there are any **backend_model columns** which have `value = Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime` in the **eav_attribute table**.

If yes, edit them to `value = Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime`

Next, do the same action, check whether there are any **frontend_model columns** which have `value = Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime`
then change them to `value = Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime`

And finally, check whether there are any **attribute_model columns** which have `value = Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime` then edit them to `value = null`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a change in the migration mapping files I had overlooked. I had the same problem, added a class in /vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Datetime.php.

One of those nice things you find out after moving things into production :-(

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data;

use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

/**
 * EAV Entity Attribute Date Data Model
 *
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Datetime extends Date
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

edit attribute 'mailchimp_sync_delta' frontend_input datetime to date worked for me.