# User registration error after migration

Tags: magento2, migration, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration-tool, customer-registration

After Migration `from Magento 1.9.2.4 to Magento 2.3.4` when I go to create a customer and fill all the information and click on submit(on front-end), it shows me an error

```
We can't save the customer.
```

After debugging I found the error below:

```
Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime does not exist
```

I tried to search the class on the database and also in files, with no results.
However, I found something similar in the table `eav_attribute`:

```
Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\Datetime
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/311577/85907

Comment: Yes, I have already consulted it, but as I said before, I have not found anything in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Please open this file

> vendor\magento\module-customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost.php

And then replace

```
$this->messageManager->addException($e, $e->getMessage());
```

With this code

```
$this->messageManager->addException($e, __('We can\'t save the customer.'));
```

So, you can get actual error and you can trace it.

Happy Coding.

Comment: That's just what I did in the debug phase and I had the following error:`Class Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Datetime does not exist`